# Ошибка при работе с AIDL

Tags: java, android, aidl

В своем приложении использую IPC. Но время от времени на устройствах ниже API 21 выскакивает такая ошибка. Может кто знает из-за чего она бывает. И как её исправить?

```
03-11 17:05:53.105 5702-5740/com.example.avest.tlswebview E/JavaBinder: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
03-11 17:05:53.105 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.nativeWriteFileDescriptor(Native Method)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.writeFileDescriptor(Parcel.java:552)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.writeToParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:420)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at com.example.aidl.INativeCrypto$Stub$Proxy.SSL_shutdown(INativeCrypto.java:8627)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at com.example.conscryptsdk.service.ServiceCrypto.SSL_shutdown(ServiceCrypto.java:2847)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at com.example.conscryptsdk.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:994)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at com.example.conscryptsdk.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:988)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoUtils.closeQuietly(IoUtils.java:76)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.closeSocketAndStreams(HttpConnection.java:134)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.release(HttpEngine.java:526)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.unexpectedEndOfInput(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:105)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.close(FixedLengthInputStream.java:69)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:134)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(Native Method)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1093)
03-11 17:05:53.140 5702-5740/com.example.tlswebview W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```